# CL-WHO-like HTML templating for other languages?

Tags: html, common-lisp, templating

Common Lisp guys have their [CL-WHO](http://www.weitz.de/cl-who/), which makes HTML templating integrated with the "main" language thus making the task easier. For those who don't know CL-WHO, it looks like this (example from CL-WHO's webpage):

```
(with-html-output (*http-stream*)
(:table :border 0 :cellpadding 4
  (loop for i below 25 by 5
     do (htm
         (:tr :align "right"
          (loop for j from i below (+ i 5)
                do (htm
                    (:td :bgcolor (if (oddp j)
                                    "pink"
                                    "green")
                         (fmt "~@R" (1+ j))))))))))
```

Do you know any libraries like this for other languages? The one I know about (that mimics CL-WHO) is [Brevé](http://breve.twisty-industries.com/) for Python. I'm particularly interested in Perl flavour, but it's interesting how other languages handle integrating HTML into their syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org) offerings have a look at the following (in alphabetical order)...

- [Builder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Builder/)
- [HTML::AsSubs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree/lib/HTML/AsSubs.pm)
- [HTML::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tiny/)
- [Markapl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Markapl/)
- [Template::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Declare/)
- [XML::Generator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Generator/)

Using the table part of the CL-WHO example provided (minus Roman numerals and s/background-color/color/ to squeeze code into screen width here!)....

### Builder

```
use Builder;
my $builder = Builder->new;
my $h = $builder->block( 'Builder::XML' );

$h->table( { border => 0, cellpadding => 4 }, sub {
   for ( my $i = 1; $i < 25; $i += 5 ) {
       $h->tr( { align => 'right' }, sub {
           for my $j (0..4) {
               $h->td( { color => $j % 2 ? 'pink' : 'green' }, $i + $j );
           }
       });
   } 
});

say $builder->render;
```

### HTML::AsSubs

```
use HTML::AsSubs;

my $td = sub {
    my $i = shift;
    return map { 
        td( { color => $_ % 2 ? 'pink' : 'green' }, $i + $_ )
    } 0..4;
};

say table( { border => 0, cellpadding => 4 },
    map { 
        &tr( { align => 'right' }, $td->( $_ ) ) 
    } loop( below => 25, by => 5 )
)->as_HTML;
```

### HTML::Tiny

```
use HTML::Tiny;
my $h = HTML::Tiny->new;

my $td = sub {
    my $i = shift;
    return map { 
        $h->td( { 'color' => $_ % 2 ? 'pink' : 'green' }, $i + $_ )
    } 0..4;
};

say $h->table(
    { border => 0, cellpadding => 4 },
    [
        map { 
            $h->tr( { align => 'right' }, [ $td->( $_ ) ] )  
        } loop( below => 25, by => 5 )    
    ]
);
```

### Markapl

```
use Markapl;

template 'MyTable' => sub {
    table ( border => 0, cellpadding => 4 ) {
       for ( my $i = 1; $i < 25; $i += 5 ) {
           row ( align => 'right' ) {
               for my $j ( 0.. 4 ) {
                   td ( color => $j % 2 ? 'pink' : 'green' ) { $i + $j }
               }
           }
       } 
    }
};

print main->render( 'MyTable' );
```

### Template::Declare

```
package MyTemplates;
use Template::Declare::Tags;
use base 'Template::Declare';

template 'MyTable' => sub {
    table {
        attr { border => 0, cellpadding => 4 };
        for ( my $i = 1; $i < 25; $i += 5 ) {
            row  {
                attr { align => 'right' };
                    for my $j ( 0..4 ) {
                        cell {
                            attr { color => $j % 2 ? 'pink' : 'green' } 
                            outs $i + $j;
                        }
                    }
            }
        } 
    }
};

package main;
use Template::Declare;
Template::Declare->init( roots => ['MyTemplates'] );
print Template::Declare->show( 'MyTable' );
```

### XML::Generator

```
use XML::Generator;
my $x = XML::Generator->new( pretty => 2 );

my $td = sub {
    my $i = shift;
    return map { 
        $x->td( { 'color' => $_ % 2 ? 'pink' : 'green' }, $i + $_ )
    } 0..4;
};

say $x->table(
    { border => 0, cellpadding => 4 },
    map { 
        $x->tr( { align => 'right' }, $td->( $_ ) )  
    } loop( below => 25, by => 5 )    
);
```

*And the following can be used to produce the "loop" in HTML::AsSubs / HTML::Tiny / XML::Generator examples....*

```
sub loop {
    my ( %p ) = @_;
    my @list;

    for ( my $i = $p{start} || 1; $i < $p{below}; $i += $p{by} ) {
        push @list, $i;
    }

    return @list;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

One of [The Perl Foundation](http://www.perlfoundation.org/)'s current grant-sponsored projects (a [lightweight web framework for Perl 6](http://www.perlfoundation.org/ilya_carl_and_stephen_a_lightweight_web_framework_for_perl_6)) has working Perl6 code that [provides a similar interface](http://blogs.gurulabs.com/stephen/2009/03/tagspm-for-the-perl-6-web-proj.html):

```
use Tags;
say show {
    html {
        head { title { 'Tags Demo' } }
        body {
            outs "hi";
            ul :id<numberlist> {
                outs "A list from one to ten:";
                for 1..10 {
                    li :class<number>, { $_ }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Browse or clone the current code on [github](http://github.com/masak/web/tree/master).

Comment: This is actually a port of Template::Declare, which you can use in perl5, today :) (http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Declare)

Answer (score 5):

Perl's CGI module has support for something like this.

```
use CGI ':standard';
use Lisp::Fmt 

print header();

print table( { -border => 1, -cellpading => 4},
    loop({ below => 25, by=> 5}, sub {
        my $i = shift;
        tr( {-align => 'right'} ,
            loop({ from => $i, below $i + 5}, sub {
                my $j = shift;
                td({-bgcolor => ($oddp eq $j ? 'pink' : 'green')}
                    fmt("~@R", 1+$j);
            })
        )
    });
```

I tried to keep it lispy, so you'll have to implement a lispy `loop` function yourself. I don't really program Common List, so I hope I understood your code correctly.

Answer (score 4):

There is [stan](http://www.kieranholland.com/code/documentation/nevow-stan/): *An s-expression-like syntax for expressing xml in pure python*, from [Divmod's Nevow](http://divmod.org/trac/wiki/DivmodNevow). I think it's kind of what you want. An example from the tutorial linked:

```
t = T.table[
           T.tr[
               T.td[ "Name:" ],
               T.td[ original.name ]
           ],
           T.tr[
               T.td[ "Email:" ],
               T.td[T.a(href='mailto:%s' % original.email)[ original.email ] ]
           ],
           T.tr[
               T.td[ "Password:" ],
               T.td[ "******" ]
           ],
       ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl's standard [CGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI.pm/CGI.pm) module can do something similar:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw/:standard/;

print 
    start_html("An example"),
    h1(
        {
            -align => "left",
            -class => "headerinfo",
        },
        'this is an example'
    ),
    "The CGI module has functions that add HTML:",
    ul( map li($_),
        ("start_html",
        "h1, h2, h3, etc.",
        "ol, ul, li",
        "ol, ul, li",
        "table, tr, th, td")
    ),
    "and many more.",
    end_html();
```

That produces:

```
<!DOCTYPE html
        PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head>
<title>An example</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
<h1 class="headerinfo" align="left">this is an example</h1>The CGI module has functions that add HTML:<ul><li>start_html</li> <li>h1, h2, h3, etc.</li> <li>ol, ul, li</li> <li>ol, ul, li</li> <li>table, tr, th, td</li></ul>and many more.
</body>
</html>
```

The li section could be rewritten like this

```
print ol(map li($_), @list);
```

if you had a list or an array.

Comment: maybe add some attributes to your example?

Answer (score 3):

### Clojure

There are a bunch of CL-WHO-inspired HTML-generating libraries available in Clojure (as one would expect, Clojure being a Lisp).  Here's how you could do it using the HTML library that comes with [Compojure](http://github.com/weavejester/compojure/tree/master), and [cl-format](http://github.com/tomfaulhaber/cl-format/tree/master):

```
(use 'compojure.html
     'com.infolace.format)

(html
 [:table {:border 0 :cellpadding 4}
  (map (fn [tds] [:tr {:align "right"} tds])
       (partition 5 (map (fn [num color]
                           [:td {:bgcolor color}
                            (cl-format nil "~@R" (inc num))])
                         (range 25)
                         (cycle ["green" "pink"]))))])
```

Compojure's HTML library makes good use of Clojure's literal hash-maps as attribute/value pairs, and using literal vectors for tags instead of lists for everything helps the tags stand out a bit and avoids some of the need for macro magic.

`partition` breaks up a collection into groups of some number of elements.  `cycle` generates an infinitely repeating list of the elements of a collection.  These plus `range` and `map` help you avoid explicit loops and counter variables.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but didn't the HTML generating functionality move out of Compojure and got placed into Hiccup?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://elzr.com/posts/hyperscript) is such thing for JavaScript. It looks like the following:

```
T.div({ className: "content"},
      T.p("Some ", T.u("paragraph")),
      T.p("Another paragraph"))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

Haskell has an HTML combinator library that is not all that different from CL-WHO. The lazy functional approach to programming, though, does result in a much different idiomatic iteration structure than the loop facilities in Common Lisp:

```
import Data.Char
import Data.List
import Text.Html
-- from http://fawcett.blogspot.com/2007/08/roman-numerals-in-haskell.html
import RomanNumerals

-- Simple roman numeral conversion; returns "" if it cannot convert.
rom :: Int -> String
rom r = let m = toRoman r
        in (map toUpper . maybe "" id) m

-- Group a list N elements at a time.
-- groupN 2 [1,2,3,4,5] == [[1,2],[3,4],[5]]
groupN n [] = []
groupN n xs = let (a, b) = splitAt n xs in a : (groupN n b)

pink = "pink" -- for convenience below; green is already covered by Text.Html

rom_table = table ! [border 0, cellpadding 4] << trs
    where
      -- a list of <tr> entries
      trs = map (rom_tr . map rom_td) rom_array

      -- generates a <tr> from a list of <td>s
      rom_tr tds = tr ! [align "right"] << tds

      -- generates a <td> given a numeral and a color
      rom_td (r, c) = td ! [bgcolor c] << r

      -- our 5 x 5 array (list x list) of numerals and colors
      rom_array = (groupN 5 . take 25) rom_colors

      -- a theoretically infinite list of pairs of roman numerals and colors
      -- (practically, though, the roman numeral library has limits!)
      rom_colors = zip (map rom [1..]) colors

      -- an infinite list of alternating green and pink colors
      colors = cycle [green, pink]

main = let s = prettyHtml rom_table 
       in putStrLn s
```

I should note there's also a little combinator library in Text.Html for composing tables using "above" and "beside" operators to calculate row/column spanning, but it's a little too simplistic in terms of applying attributes to duplicate this example exactly, and we don't need the fancy splitting of rows and columns.

Answer (score 1):

There's [html-tags](http://wiki.call-cc.org/egg/html-tags), a [Chicken Scheme](http://call-cc.org) extension. html-tags generates either [X]HTML or SXML.

Here's an example (using the loop extension and considering string output):

```
(<table> border: 0 cellpadding: 4
  (string-intersperse
   (loop for i below 25 by 5
         collect
         (<tr> align: "right"
               (string-intersperse
                (loop for j from i below (+ i 5)
                      collect
                      (<td> bgcolor: (if (odd? j)
                                         "pink"
                                         "green")
                            (+ 1 j))))))))
```

I'd add links to the loop and html-utils extensions (which is built on top of html-tags), but stackoverflow is considering I'm a spammer and only allows me to post a maximum of two links.

Answer (score 0):

Racket's built-in [XML library](https://docs.racket-lang.org/xml/index.html) has this capability. It is capable of generating XML/HTML from "X-expressions". For example:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require xml)

(define my-name "XYZ")
(define my-list '("One" "Two" "Three"))
(define my-html
  `(html
     (head (title "Hello!")
           (meta ((charset "utf-8"))))
     (body (h1 "Hello!")
           (p "This is a paragraph.")

           ;; HTML attributes.
           (p ((id "some-id")
               (class "some-class"))
              "This is another paragraph.")
           (p "This is a link: " (a ((href "https://example.com")) "Example"))

           ;; Unquoting.
           (p "My name is: " ,my-name ".")
           (p ,(string-append "My name is: " my-name "."))  ; Same thing.

           (ul (li "One")
               (li "Two")
               (li "Three"))
           ;; Programatically generate the same list as above.
           (ul ,@(map (lambda (x)
                        `(li ,x))
                      my-list))

           ,(comment "This is a HTML comment."))))

(displayln (string-append "<!DOCTYPE html>"
                          (xexpr->string my-html)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[domonic](https://pypi.org/project/domonic/) is a python library that uses magic methods and dunders to try and support this kind of thing...

```
from domonic.html import *
mydom = html(body(h1('Hello, World!')))
print(f"{mydom}")
```

docs...
https://domonic.readthedocs.io/packages/html.html

```
pip install domonic
```