# python and ruby equivalent of perls Template::Declare?

Tags: python, ruby, perl

CPAN has the [Template::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Template::Declare) package. A declarative way to create HTML templates in Perl without any HTML directly written.

I would love to use similar packages in python and ruby. Are there equivalent packages for those languages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Ruby there is [`Markaby`](http://markaby.rubyforge.org/).  The *closest* I know if in Python is [`Brevé`](http://breve.twisty-industries.com/).

Also there are a few more in [`Perl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671572/cl-who-like-html-templating-for-other-languages/672665#672665) and [other languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671572/cl-who-like-html-templating-for-other-languages) as well.

/I3az/

Comment: That is pretty much what i was looking for. Thanks for the link to the other question.

Answer (score 1):

If you like the look of Markaby, also see [Erector](http://erector.rubyforge.org/) which is inspired by it but said to be somewhat cleaner

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like [Haml](http://haml-lang.com/tutorial.html) in Ruby ?

Example for Ruby :

```
$ sudo gem install haml
$ irb
> require 'haml'
> Haml::Engine.new('%p Hello, World').render
=> "<p>Hello, World</p>\n"
```

Comment: I know haml but it is still a different language. I would like ruby templating in ruby code and python templating in python code.