# Is there a small Perl XML parser that can replace CGI.pm's HTML generation functions?

Tags: xml, perl, templates

Is there any little (1-2 .pm's) parser based around XML::* and suitable for replacing CGI.pm's constructions like:

```
foreach($xmlnodes) {
    print table( TR( td( $_) ) ); }
```

with node2html($node,$rules)?

I ain't going to fire up XSLT.

Comment: This is really unclear.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it `push style` templating you're thinking of? ie. take a plain HTML file as the template and using CSS or XSLT selectors to push content into it?

If so then two CPAN modules I've used to do this are:

- [`HTML::Zoom`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Zoom/)
- [`Template::Semantic`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Semantic/)

Also see the [Perlmonks](http://www.perlmonks.org) post called [Push style templating systems](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=674225) which provides more information including a list of push  style templates available.

If not push style then are you looking for HTML builders?  If so see this Stackoverflow question: [CL-WHO-like HTML templating for other languages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671572/cl-who-like-html-templating-for-other-languages)

/I3az/

Answer (score 5):

Whenever you want to find modules, search [CPAN](http://search.cpan.org). Have a look around, and see what you like. The more you do it, the better sense of the landscape you'll have. Soon, you won't even have to ask. :)

I'm not sure what you are asking about, though, because you say "parser" but it seems that you want to go the other way. If you want to rewrite XML, I might recommend [XML::Twig](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig).

Comment: "Soon, you won't even have to ask. :)" - wishful thinking I fear.